# pass serialized objects to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to send an object through several activity, adapter and fragment to load an information.
the navigation of the object with the information would be like this:

activity A -> activity B -> fragment -> adapter -> activity

Activity A: place where I send the data and I already probe it and they get right to the activity B

```
 public void actualizarVista(DataBaseDTO dataBaseDTO){

        if (dataBaseDTO.getEntidad() != null && dataBaseDTO.getOperacion().equals(EnumOperaciones.CONSULTAR_ESTUDIANTE_CEDULA.getOperacion()))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, MenuActivity.class);

            Estudiante datosest = (Estudiante) dataBaseDTO.getEntidad();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("Estudiante", datosest);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }else if (dataBaseDTO.getEntidad() != null && dataBaseDTO.getOperacion().equals(EnumOperaciones.CONSULTAR_PROFESOR_CEDULA.getOperacion())){

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, Menu_profesor.class);

            Profesor datosprof = (Profesor) dataBaseDTO.getEntidad();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("Profesor", datosprof);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }else{
            notificar(dataBaseDTO);
        }    
    }
```

Activity B:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        setTitle("Profesores disponibles");
        Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Bundle  datos = getIntent().getExtras();
        estu = (Estudiante) datos.getSerializable("Estudiante");

        DrawerLayout drawer =  findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        nombreNav =  headerView.findViewById(R.id.lbNombreNav);
        correoNav = headerView.findViewById(R.id.navCorreoEst);

        nombreNav.setText(estu.getNombre());
        correoNav.setText(estu.getCorreo());

        Fragment listarProfesorFragment = new ListarProfesorFragment();

        listarProfesorFragment.setArguments(datos);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.contenidomenuestudiante, new ListarProfesorFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();    
    }
```

Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
    View viewListarProfesores = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menuest_inicial, viewGroup, false);
    listprofesores = viewListarProfesores.findViewById(R.id.listProfesor);

      Bundle data = this.getArguments();
     objetoEstudiante = (Estudiante) data.getSerializable("Estudiante");

     Log.e("ERROR", "" + data);

    return viewListarProfesores;
}
```

When I access the data in the fragment, I get an error, the data is null. I do not know the correct way to do it.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: Implement Serializable in your model Class
like This

```
public class Estudiante implements Serializable{

}
```

To Get Serializable in Fragment you have to do like this..

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "obj";
    private Estudiante object;
    public BlankFragment() {
    }
    public static BlankFragment newInstance(Estudiante param1) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            object = (Estudiante) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        // Use object
        return view;
    }

}
```

Step:3 While passing object to fragment just do this

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, BlankFragment.newInstance(new Estudiante()));
        transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try it. I have a concern, there is some way in which I can create a class to save the object and access it from anywhere in the application, either an activity or fragment

Comment: Make it static like public static Estudiante object;
assign its value and in anywhere in App you can Access it with class ref# where u created it like MainActivity.object etc

Answer (score 0):

you can change your method,
in order bundle, pass it as parameter to fragment
in your newInstance method of your fragment add a parameter like this

```
public static ListarProfesorFragment newInstance(Estudiante estu){
    ...
    objetoEstudiante = estu;
    // and here you have access to it ;-)
}
```

create newInstance method in your fragment like above, then in your activity call it

```
estu = (Estudiante) datos.getSerializable("Estudiante");
Fragment listarProfesorFragment = ListarProfesorFragment.newInstance(estu);
```

Comment: You know some more efficient way in which you do not have to send the object through the different activity fragment, something where you can access the object from anywhere, either from the activity or the fragment.

I can not understand the answer, could you be a little more specific?